# parameteres transfer in python

Tags: python, parameters, parallel-processing

I am new to Python and a bit confused about parameters transfer: 
I have 2 methods:

```
def convert(self, ipnb, indices = []):
    with self.fopen(ipnb, u'r') as f:
        emptyIndicesList = not indices
        #some code

def test_read(self):
    s = self.convert(self, u'test.ipynb')
    #some code
```

I encounter 2 issues:

1. If I run the code as is `self.fopen(ipnb, u'r') as f` throws...
   But if I change `with self.fopen(ipnb, u'r') as f` to 
        `self.fopen(u'test.ipynb', u'r') as f` it works properly
2. `emptyIndicesList` is `false`, I expect it to be `true`, since I think that I am using default parameter - empty list
   What am I missing in parameter transfer? How the above issues should be solved?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the context as a first argument to the function **convert**.

Change  `s = self.convert(self, u'test.ipynb')` to `s = self.convert(u'test.ipynb')` which shall resolve both of your issues.